# Cannot open file handle from a variable

Tags: perl, file-io

Initially I have run the shell script and direct the output into a file and then use Perl to reading the file and parse it. I wanted to put these two steps together into one Perl script.

And I tried to write something like this:

```
my $in = 'file.txt';
my $read = qx(samtools view -S $in |cut -f 3|sort|uniq -c|awk '{OFS="\t";print \$2,\$1}');

open (IN,"<",$read) || die "cannot open $read: $!";
```

I got the error message that $in can't be opened and the result from the qx() command was printed out on the screen.

I couldn't understand why this didn't work and how to make it work..

EDIT:

The error from the open line is:

```
File name too long
```

Comment: A much better idea than this cumbersome code is to use a Perl module designed to handle the SAM format, look at https://metacpan.org/search?q=sam+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will read the output of the shell commands that you have run and store that output (anything written to STDOUT) in `$in`.

I doubt the shell command will run correctly as you are attempting to use `$in` within it, and it is probably not defined.

You can spot this if you `use strict;` at the top of the script.

```
my $in = qx(samtools view -S $in |cut -f 3|sort|uniq -c|awk '{OFS="\t";print \$2,\$1}');

// No need to open anything here, just inspect $in
```

I'm not familiar with 'samtools', but you will likely need to fix the shell command and use the right thing instead of `$in` in `view -S $in`

**EDIT**:

Okay, you're saying that your shell command writes to a file, which you then want to read.  I misunderstood!

What I have stated above remains true, but to solve your issue more fully you will need to do something like this:

```
my $in = 'file.txt';
my $cmd_output = qx(samtools view -S $in |cut -f 3|sort|uniq -c|awk '{OFS="\t";print \$2,\$1}');

open my $fh, '<', $in or die "ERROR: Couldn't open $in for reading: $!";
```

**2ND EDIT**, answering question in comments:

In order to parse the output line by line, you can just do something like this:

```
foreach my $line (split /\n/, $cmd_output) {
    // Do something with $line
}
```

To be honest, you might even find it easier to do this on the shell with:

```
$ samtools view -S $in |cut -f 3|sort|uniq -c|awk '{OFS="\t";print \$2,\$1}' | perl -lne '... do something with $_ ...'
```

Comment: sorry, i realized that i have used the same variable $in.. i've modified the question. from what i saw, the qx() actually produced the desired result. it's the redirecting into a file handle part that didn't work

Comment: Yes, if you try what amon has suggested, or also what I have suggested, you will see a more detailed error.  The $! will tell you why you cannot open the file.

Comment: Okay, you're still not trying my fix.  You are attempting to open the output of the command that you have constructed.

You need to open the file that you have written, which is in the $in variable, not the $read variable.

Comment: what's your fix? I always have use strict; at the top of my script, you mean inspect $in?

Comment: Please try the SECOND block of code in my answer.
You have "open my $fh, '<', $read" when you should have "open my $fh, '<', $in"

Comment: oh,i see. $in is the input file, i take $in and give it to samtools view -S to read. so i don't want to parse $in..

Comment: So are you intending for your shell command to output the filename that you should read?
If so, it's probably worth inspecting that.  You may like to change the error handling to: open my $fh, '<', $read or die "ERROR: Cannot read file '$read': $!" so that you can see clearly what the file that it is trying to read is

Comment: not output the filename, samtools view -S output some information the rest of the commands use to sort, get unique ones and reformat.

Comment: Then why are you trying to open it like a file?  Why don't you just use the $read variable?  It will be a string containing all of that output.

Comment: i want to parse the content line by line.. what would you do?

Comment: I've added a solution to the end of my answer as it should be easier to read than here.

Answer (score 4):

The string produced by the shell command probably contains a newline at the end. Remove it via `chomp`:

```
chomp $in;
```

Also, please use normal variables for file handles:

```
open my $fh, "<", $in or die qq(Can't open "$in": $!);
```

Comment: Should add that amon has included in his die the '$!' variable which also helps in debugging.